# Python - Duplicate values in a dictionary

Tags: python

I wrote the following code:

```
def word_len_dict(text):
    the_dict = {}
    user_input = str(text)
    words_list = user_input.split()
    for word in words_list:
        if len(word) in the_dict:
            the_dict[len(word)] += [word]
        else:
            the_dict[len(word)] = [word]
    return the_dict
```

the text is:

```
"the faith that he had had had had an affect on his life"
```

my output is coming out as:

```
2 - ['an', 'he', 'on']
3 - ['had', 'had', 'had', 'had', 'his', 'the']
4 - ['life', 'that']
5 - ['faith']
6 - ['affect']
```

I would like my output to be:

```
2 - ['an', 'he', 'on']
3 - ['had', 'his', 'the']
4 - ['life', 'that']
5 - ['faith']
6 - ['affect']
```

how do i stop it from repeating values, when adding it to the dictionary?

Comment: Ended up just making a new list without duplicate words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a set out of words_list to remove duplicates

Comment: Thank you. Ended up just making a new list without duplicate words

Answer (score 4):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def word_len_dict(text):
    words_by_len = defaultdict(set)
    for word in text.split():
        words_by_len[len(word)].add(word)
    return words_by_len

text = "the faith that he had had had had an affect on his life"
word_len_dict(text)
```

gives

```
{
    2: {'an', 'he', 'on'},
    3: {'had', 'his', 'the'},
    4: {'life', 'that'},
    5: {'faith'},
    6: {'affect'}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for word in words_list:
    if len(word) in the_dict and word not in the_dict[len(word)]:
        the_dict[len(word)] += [word]
    else if len(word) not in the_dict:
        the_dict[len(word)] = [word]
```

or just use a set

```
for k,v in the_dict.items():
    print k,":",set(v)
```

or get more clever

```
for word in words_list:
    if word not in the_dict.get(len(word),[]):
       the_dict.setdefault(len(word),[]).append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty dictionary of lists keyed on the word length of each word in the user input.  This will overwrite some keys with a new empty dictionary, but this will have no impact.

Next, you use a list comprehension to append each word of the appropriate length to the relevant key in the dictionary if it is not already present.

```
text = "the faith that he had had had had an affect on his life"
words = text.split()

# Initialize empty list based on word count.  
the_dict = {len(word): [] for word in words}

# Populate unique words in dictionary.
[the_dict[len(word)].append(word) for word in words if word not in the_dict[len(word)]]

>>> the_dict
{2: ['he', 'an', 'on'],
 3: ['the', 'had', 'his'],
 4: ['that', 'life'],
 5: ['faith'],
 6: ['affect']}
```

Wrapped in a function:

```
def word_len_dict(text):
    words = text.split()
    d = {len(word): [] for word in words}
    [d[len(word)].append(word) for word in words if word not in d[len(word)]]
    return d

>>> word_len_dict("the faith that he had had had had an affect on his life")
{2: ['he', 'an', 'on'],
 3: ['the', 'had', 'his'],
 4: ['that', 'life'],
 5: ['faith'],
 6: ['affect']}
```